# Add to cart function doesnt work on product pages

Tags: javascript, addtocart

Since activating the Porto theme on my magento site the add to cart function hasnt worked on the product pages, but still works on the catalogue views.

Does anyone have suggestions?

http://dev.tec-id.net

Many Thanks,

Luke

Comment: Check this js error - TbeAjaxAddToCartEnabler is not defined.     ajaxAddToCart = new TbeAjaxAddToCartEnabler('.btn-cart', $('product_addtocart_form'));

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of errors on the product page, the `TbeAjaxAddToCartEnabled` is the likely culprit. It hasn't been defined, maybe there is a JS file not loading or another error preventing it from being declared.

Without spending more time (I don't have) or access to the codebase it's hard for me to say the exact cause.

[image]